# How to Use Join

Tags: mysql, join, inner-join, self-join

I have table like

```
id       |  name     | manager
1        |  A        |    0 
2        |  B        |    1
3        |  C        |    2
4        |  D        |    1
```

and i want each employee name along with manager name and id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/438dd7/2

```
SELECT e.*,
        e1.name
FROM employee e
LEFT JOIN employee e1
ON e.manager = e1.id
```

Comment: Thanks it's working but could you explain it,actully i new so it's hard to understnad.

Answer (score 1):

Say your Table Name is employee and manager

```
SELECT 
e.id, 
e.name AS empname, 
m.name AS managername
FROM employee AS e 
INNER JOIN manager AS m ON e.manager = m.id
```

Hope it will help you